# Python- How can I randomise questions that have an A,B,C,D

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

My aim is to have it so it can randomise questions.

For example, the test starts and the first question could be question 8. The word `Question` is only a comment at a moment.

I want it to look like this:

```
What does OSI stand for?

A- Open Systematic Information
B- Open Systems Interconnect
C- Organised Stairway Interweb
D- Open Safe Internet
```

Here is the code:

```
#Intro

name=input("Hello, what is your name? ")
print()
print ("Hello "+ name)
print()

valid = False
while not valid:
    ready=input("Are you ready to begin the test? (Please enter YES/NO)")
    print()

    if ready.lower() =="yes":
        print ("Excellent. Welcome to the Networking Principles test. ")
        valid = True
    elif ready.lower() =="no":
        print ("Okay, tell me when your ready. ")
    else:
        print ("Please asnwer yes or no")

count=0


if ready.lower()=="yes":
    print()
    print("Please answer each answer with A,B,C or D only. The test will now begin..."
    )


#Question 1
    print()
    print('What does OSI stand for?')
    print()
    print("A- Open Systematic Information")
    print("B- Open Systems Interconnect")
    print("C- Organised Stairway Interweb")
    print("D- Open Safe Internet")
    answer = input()

    if answer.lower() =="b":
        print ("Correct, Well Done")
        count = count + 1
    else:
        print ("Wrong Answer. The asnwer was B, OSI stands for Open Systems Interconnect")


#Question 2
    print()
    print("What is the fourth Layer of the OSI Model?")
    print()
    print("A- Transport Layer")
    print("B- Teleport Layer")
    print("C- Telecommunications Layer")
    print("D- Topology Layer")
    answer = input()

    if answer.lower() =="a":
        print ("Correct, Well Done")
        count = count + 1
    else:
        print ("Wrong Answer. Layer 4 is the Transport Layer")
```

Comment: Push all quesrions to a list and if it has been chosen ranfomly, remove it from the list

Answer (score 2):

You could put answers in a list and call [`random.shuffle()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) on it:

```
import random

answers = [
    "Open Systematic Information",
    "Open Systems Interconnect",
    "Organised Stairway Interweb",
    "Open Safe Internet",
]
random.shuffle(answers)

for letter, answer in zip("ABCD", answers):
    print("{}- {}".format(letter, answer))
```

Each time you run it, it may produce different output e.g.:

```
A- Organised Stairway Interweb
B- Open Systematic Information
C- Open Safe Internet
D- Open Systems Interconnect
```

Comment: Okay good, Liking the random shuffle. But how would I then randomise the questions?

Comment: random.shuffle() randomizes the questions. Try to run it

Answer (score 2):

You could hold all of your questions in a list of dictionaries:

```
questions = [{'question': 'What does OSI stand for?',
              'correct': ['Open Systems Interconnect'],
              'incorrect': ['Open Systematic Information', 
                            'Organised Stairway Interweb',
                            'Open Safe Internet']},
             {'question': "What is the fourth Layer of the OSI Model?",
              'correct': ['Transport Layer'],
              'incorrect': ['Teleport Layer', 
                            'Telecommunications Layer', 
                            'Topology Layer']}, 
             ...]
```

Now you can give the user a given number of randomly-selected questions each time:

```
import random
import string

to_answer = random.sample(questions, number_of_questions)
```

And then ask the question:

```
for q_num, question in enumerate(to_answer, 1):
    print("Question {0}: {1}".format(q_num, question['question']))
```

and present the answers in a random order, storing each against the corresponding key (`a`, `b`, `c`, etc.) in `answer_key`:

```
    answers = question['incorrect'] + question['correct']
    random.shuffle(answers)
    answer_key = {}
    for answer, key in zip(answers, string.ascii_lowercase):
        print("{0}: {1}".format(key, answer))
        answer_key[key] = answer
```

Take the user's input:

```
    while True:
        user_answer = input().lower()
        if user_answer not in answer_key:
            print("Not a valid answer")
        else:
            break
```

And finally check whether they're correct and report back:

```
    correct = question['correct']
    if answer_key[user_answer] in correct:
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        s = "Incorrect; the correct answer{0}:"
        print(s.format(" was" if len(correct) == 1 else "s were"))
        for answer in correct:
            print(answer)
```

This supports the possibility of multiple correct answers for a single question, and hard-codes as little as possible so the whole thing is configured by `questions`. That reduces repetition of code, and makes it easier to find bugs later on.

Example output (for `number_of_questions = 1` and `questions` as shown above):

```
Question 1: What does OSI stand for?
a: Open Systematic Information
b: Open Safe Internet
c: Organised Stairway Interweb
d: Open Systems Interconnect
e
Not a valid answer
b
Incorrect; the correct answer was:
Open Systems Interconnect
```

Comment: Okay whilst your feedback Is good, how would I add the answers? Like what would be the example input for the example output you just gave.

Comment: ...the input is at the start of the question. It is a list of dictionaries, one for each question: `[{'question': questiontext, 'correct': correctanswerlist, 'incorrect': incorrectanswerlist}, ...]`

Comment: Im afraid I do not understand. Especially this part=   "Incorrect" : incorrectanswerlist  Do you wish me to style it like this= 'incorrect': Open Systems Interconnect.

Comment: No, it should be a list of the answers that are not correct, `'incorrect': ['Open Systematic Information', ...]`, then the answers are in the list `'correct': ['Open Systems Interconnect']`. This is literally the first part of my answer, please look at the example there.

Answer (score 1):

you can do simple one pulling information from files like so,

```
while count < 10:
wordnum = random.randint(0, len(questionsfile)-1)
print 'What is:  ', answersfile[wordnum], ''
options = [random.randint(0, len(F2c)-1),
    random.randint(0, len(answersfile)-1),random.randint(0, len(answersfile)-1)]
options[random.randint(0, 2)] = wordnum
print '1 -', answersfile[options[0]],
print '2 -', answersfile[options[1]],
print '3 -', answersfile[options[2]],
print '4 -', answersfile[options[3]]
answer = input('\nYou  choose number ?: ')
if options[answer-1] == wordnum:
```

Comment: There is also this function in python as well to randomize your questions without having the answers repeat in the answer option, the function is random.samlple.

Answer (score -1):

Name `QuestionX`.
Then choose one from or shuffle these `QuestionX` randomly.

For example:

```
import random
def Question1():
    print('Q1:What does OSI stand for?')
    answer = raw_input()
    print(answer)

def Question2():
    print("Q2:What is the fourth Layer of the OSI Model?")
    answer = raw_input()
    print(answer)

Questions = [Question1, Question2]

#Solution 1
q = random.choice(Questions)
q()

#Solution 2
for q in random.sample(Questions, len(Questions)):
    q()

#Solution 3
random.shuffle(Questions)
for q in Questions:
    q()
```

If you want to shuffle choices in the question.
You can do same above.

```
def Question1():
    print('What does OSI stand for?')
    def A(): print("A- Open Systematic Information")
    def B(): print("B- Open Systems Interconnect")
    def C(): print("C- Organised Stairway Interweb")
    def D(): print("D- Open Safe Internet")
    choices = [A, B, C, D]
    random.shuffle(choices)
    for c in choices:
        c()

Question1()
```

Output:

```
What does OSI stand for?
B- Open Systems Interconnect
D- Open Safe Internet
C- Organised Stairway Interweb
A- Open Systematic Information
```

As you can see in the output, it seems you shouldn't hard-code the name of choices. You should add A,B,C,D after shuffling.

Comment: This will mean repeating the same code multiple times for each `Question` function, introducing plenty of sources of error and making maintenance more difficult, and, as you point out in your answer, also shuffles the answer letters.