# Python 2.6 Trivia game, multiple choice and true/false at random

Tags: python, python-2.6

```
import random
players = 0
player1 = 0
player2 = 0

def open_file(file_name, mode):
    try:
        the_file = open(file_name, mode)
    except(IOError), e:
        print 'Cannot open file', file_name + '. Try moving its location.'
        raw_input('\nPress enter to exit. ')
        sys.exit()
    else:
        return the_file

def next_line(the_file):
    line = the_file.readline()
    line = line.replace('/', '\n')
    return line

def main():    
    file = open_file('Trivia_Questions.txt', 'r')
    questions = file.read().split('\n\n')
    file.close()
    random.shuffle(questions)
    for question in questions.splitlines():
        if next_line(question) == 'Multiple Choice':
            subject, question, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, reason, empty  = map(question)
            print subject
            print question
            print '1 -', answer1
            print '1 -', answer1
            print '1 -', answer1
            print '1 -', answer1
            print reason
            subject, question, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, reason, empty = next_block(file)
        else:
            subject, question, answer1, answer2, reason, empty = map(question)
            print subject
            print question
            print '1 -', answer1
            print '2 -', answer2
            print reason
            print empty
            subject, question, answer1, answer2, reason, empty = next_block(file)



main()
```

I have been looking up on how to go about doing this, and have no idea what to do.
When I attempt to run this code i get

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'splitlines'
```

My txt file is setup like
mult choice
question
answer1
answer2
answer3
answer4
correct answer#
reasonwhy

true/false
question
t
f
correct t or f
reasonwhy

repeat 12x

ive been searching online for 2 days before i decided to ask so any assistance would be much appreciated. I need to correctly have a trivia game randomly select a question, whether its true/false for mult choice, not use the question again.

Comment: You might find my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22510326/3001761) useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *already* split your file into a list:

```
questions = file.read().split('\n\n')
```

so `questions` is a list here. You cannot then try to split `questions` into a new list here:

```
for question in questions.splitlines():
```

If you wanted to split each *individual question* into separate lines, do so in the loop:

```
for question in questions:
    for questionline in question.splitlines()
```

Comment: i made the changes you suggested, then i got an error saying map needs 2 args. i then changed the next_line() func to replace the '/' value with '\n', now im getting

    valueerror: too many subjects to unpack

Comment: @user3407712: it is unclear what you are trying to do there; `map()` is probably not the function you are looking for in the first place.