# Avoid repetitive answer in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am making a flash card program to help me memorize python keywords and terms. but sometimes it repeat the answer for me which is obvious to anyone to guess.

> What is: Exception
>       1- Another name for runtime error
>       2- Another name for runtime error
>       3- The meaning of a program

So how do I avoid this repetitive ?

```
while count < 10:
os.system('clear')
wordnum = random.randint(0, len(F1c)-1)
print "What is:  ", F1c[wordnum], ""
options = [random.randint(0,len(F2c)-1),random.randint(0,len(F2c)-1),
random.randint(0,len(F2c)-1)]
options[random.randint(0, 2)] = wordnum
print '1 -', F2c[options[0]],
print '2 -', F2c[options[1]],
print '3 -', F2c[options[2]],
answer = input('\nYou  choose number ?:')
if options[answer-1] == wordnum:
    raw_input('\nCorrect! Hit enter...')
    score = score + 1
else:
    raw_input('\nWrong! Hit enter...')
count = count + 1
print '\nYour score is:', score
```

Comment: You might find my (overlong) [answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22510326/3001761) useful.

Comment: Didn't quit find it, but was really helpful, Thank will check more time in the entire post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you do nothing to ensure that second and third selected option won't clash with first. In order to do so you can remove first chosen option from list before choosing second, and so on.

However, there is function in python standard library that already implements carefully selecting several items from a list:

```
answers = random.sample(F2c, 3)
```

Or to select indexes:

```
options = random.sample(range(len(F2c)), 3)
```

Comment: I am sorry sir, I may not get what you talking about exactly, what is this function name ?

Comment: I mean `random.sample` https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample.