# Alternative to eval to create a generic function that can process multiple variables

Tags: python, eval

For a set of games I'm creating I have a line a code that allows a question to be answered only once. If it has been answered, it adds points to a player's score (the code below sits inside of an if function that checks the answer) and then shuts off the ability to answer the question again. Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
while self.game1_question1_not_answered:
    self.game1_player1_score += self.score_increment
    self.game1_question1_not_answered = False`
```

I would like to use the 'game1' in the code as a generic identifier that can be used to identify any one of the multiple games I'm creating. I tried using a variable called game_name (e.g., game_name = game1) and inserting the variable into the code using an eval function but haven't gotten the code to work. In addition, I realize the eval function has some security concerns. What function could I use to get this to work? The code I've tried that doesn't work looks like this:

```
while eval('self.' + game_name + 'question1_not_answered'):
    eval('self.' + game_name + 'player1_score') += self.score_increment
    eval('self.' + game_name + 'question1_not_answered') = False
```

Is there another function I could use instead of eval to get this to work?

Comment: Don't do that. If you have multiple games, *make them separate instances*. You should try to keep data out of your attribute names.

Comment: Indeed, note that you can get even more data out of your variable names by having a list `game.questions` in which each item is a `Question` instance with the boolean attribute `answered`.

Comment: @jonsharpe Can you say more on why it's best practice to make the games separate instances? We originally had them as separate instances but this made our code very long and redundant. Our code has to be efficient because it's being packaged into a mobile app using Kivy (the app loaded very slowly once we added multiple games as separate instances) so we think creating one method to process multiple games is the way to go . However, I'm new to python so am open to any advice you may have. thanks

Comment: It's hard to give further advice without seeing more of the code, but it seems unlikely that this is the most efficient implementation from either a development or deployment perspective. The point of classes is to *reduce* duplication, so if you found the opposite your model may not have been appropriate. If the overhead of a class isn't necessary (e.g. if there are no methods), consider nesting dictionaries instead. You could try taking your code over to http://codereview.stackexchange.com for more thorough feedback.

Comment: thanks @johsharpe - great advice. Will work on building a dictionary based solution and will also head over to code review for more thoughts. Didn't realize this resource existed!

Comment: No problem - you might find e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22510326/3001761) useful.

Comment: thanks again @jonsharpe. The multiple choice example was useful - I will be integrating it into my code. Only small change is that I had to use raw_input rather then input when defining use_answer. Cheers

Comment: Yes, that's a 2.x vs 3.x thing (`raw_input` is renamed `input` in Py3.x, and `input` (i.e. `eval(raw_input(...))`) is gone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd actually follow @jonrsharpe's comment, but if you really need to have them in one instance, you can use `getattr` and `setattr` builtins:

```
     game_name = "game1"
     question1_na_line = "{}_question1_not_answered"
     player1_sc_line = "{}_player1_score"

     question1_na = question1_na_line.format(game_name)
     player1_sc = player1_sc_line.format(game_name)
     while getattr(self, question1_na):
         setattr(self,
                 player1_sc,
                 getattr(self, player1_sc) + self.score_increment)
         setattr(self, question1_na, False)
```

Comment: thanks @pavel_form - this works perfectly. However, now trying to figure it whether this is the best way to go given we're building a mobile app. Let me know if you have any thoughts on my comment to jonsharpe above

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `dict` instead. That will allow you to create dynamically-named variables, as it were, to store that information.

```
self.game_dict = {}
self.game_dict[game_name + 'question1_not_answered'] = True
```

Then you can modify it as above, and access it in a couple ways:

```
>>> game_obj.game_dict.get(game_name + 'question1_not_answered')
True
>>> game_obj.game_dict[game_name + 'question1_not_answered']
True
```

But as jonrsharpe said, your variable names should not include data. The best solution would be to make multiple game objects, each with variables like `question1_not_answered`. Then if you need to, assign all of those objects to variables in whatever `self` is in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to access attributes by name is the `getattr(obj, name)` function. Now given the more specific problem you describe I think you'd be better using a dict (or dict of dicts etc) to store your games states (scores etc).